# Mac 10.6.7 Firefox office 2011 file association for all users

Tags: mac-osx, firefox

I need to work out a way to have Firefox 4 or 3.6 on OSX to auto open Word, Excel and Powerpoint file types from a local intranet.

I have setup Firefox under a localuseradmin with the file types set to open automaticly and then I copied the Firefox/Mozilla folders into the /system/library/user template/ but when a new user logs in the file type association is set back to default when Firefox runs.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox supports a global preferences file which sets defaults for users who don't already have a preference setting of their own. This file can also contain "lockPref" entries, which sets preferences even if the users do already have their own setting.

[This link](http://mockbox.net/configmgr-sccm/300-firefox-4-set-default-home-page-for-all-users.html) details setting up a system-wide home page in Firefox 4. The instructions are for Windows, but they should work fine on Mac OS X with the appropriate paths.